# How do I write documents using llncs.cls without having to put it in the same folder as the document?

Tags: installing, linux, texmf, lncs

I'm using Linux Mint, with the TeX Live distro and Texmaker as my editor. Basically, I would like to be able to use `llncs.cls` as a document class without having to always put that file in with the document I'm trying to compile. Under MikTeX (which I used back when I used Windows), there was a way to resolve it by giving it a place to search for packages etc. if it couldn't find them normally. However, I have no idea how to do this in Linux. Could someone help me out?

Comment: I think, your paths to the `TeXLive` distribution are corrupted or something is strange with `TexMaker` configuration. `11ncs.cls` is not provided by `TeXLive`, is it? Did you have a look, whether that class file is installed in your `TexLive` distribution or not, for example another storage position could be `/usr/local/share/texmf` or something like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All TeX Live installations allow for a “personal tree”; on GNU/Linux systems this tree is rooted in `~/texmf`, where `~` stands for your home directory.

Just issue this pair of commands from a directory where you keep a copy of `llncs.sty`:

```
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/llncs
cp llncs.cls $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/llncs/
```

Using `~/texmf` instead of `$(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME)` is possible, but the longer method is independent of where the “personal tree” actually is defined to be found at (on Mac OS X, with MacTeX, it's rooted in a different place).

After doing this, `llncs.cls` will be available for every LaTeX run, independently of the working directory.

Comment: That's a good tutorial, do you think it should be merged into [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files](the canonical question on this topic)?

Comment: @tohecz Please, do!